# Concatenate all combinations of DataFrames from a list to calculate correlation to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, python-itertools

i tried and searched many houres to find a solution for my problem without success.
I hope i can describe my problem as clear as possible:

**General situation:**

My goal is to find the best combinations of features from different DataFrames for machine learning.
Therefore, i want to calculate the correlation of each feature in single version vs. my "target_column", but also the combinations (e.g. df1+df2 vs. target_column, df2+df3+df4 vs. target_column, ...).

Restrictive issues:

1. The DataFrames are very large --> 5´000´000 observations per DataFrame
2. My computer has 16 GB memory (i got a lot of memory errors during my work)

**Description of my main problem:**

I have a list of Dataframes: `list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]`
Each DataFrame is represented in pandas.get_dummies representation (because many categorical features).
I can pd.concat them, because they already represent information for the same observations.

I want to have all combinations of the list_of_dfs for following goal:

1. pd.concat them to a new DataFrame
2. Calculate the correlation of this DataFrame to my target_column (not included in the dfs from list_of_dfs)

My current approach:

```
def get_df_name(df):
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    return name


def corr(df1, df2):
    n = len(df1)
    v1, v2 = df1.values, df2.values
    sums = np.multiply.outer(v2.sum(0), v1.sum(0))
    stds = np.multiply.outer(v2.std(0), v1.std(0))
    print(get_df_name(df1))
    return pd.DataFrame((v2.T.dot(v1) - sums / n) / stds / n, df2.columns, df1.columns)


from itertools import combinations 
for i in range(6):
  list_of_dummies_comb = combinations(list_of_dfs, i)
  # test = pd.concat(list_of_dummies_comb, axis=1)
  # print(corr(test, target_column).median())
```

In the last two lines of code, I have the problem that i have to deal with class.tuple and I got an error that I can´t concat them.

Has somebody an idea or a solution for my problem or my approach?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you be willing to move the computation to cloud services? The long way on your machine would be taking combinations of columns of each one of your dataframes (df1.col1+df2.col1, df1.col1+df2.col2...) and storing the correlations in a matrix as you go. Or you could spin up a large EC2 instance on AWS and just concat all of the DFs and compute a single correlation matrix.

Comment: @SavageHenry thanks for your answer :)
I would like to avoid consuming aws or netcup instances for this step, because when i did my feature selection step, I can use compressed sparse matrices for regression / classification models which don´t need much computation power or memory :)
Do you have an alternative solution how I can deal with this situation? :)

Comment: If you have to live within the memory constraints, you could do what I note above: get the correlations of the full combination of all columns, doing two-at-a-time, and store them in a matrix. Each computation shouldn't be hard, but depending on the number of columns, could take a while (write results to disk to save progress). Or, you could look into things like [Dask](https://dask.org/) to see if you could actually concat all the DFs at once and just get the corr(DF) results.

Comment: I got an useful answer, which solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112616/combinations-of-dataframes-from-list/60112952#60112952