# Combinations of DataFrames from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have this:

`dfs_in_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]`

I want to concatenate all combinations of them one after the other (in a loop), like:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) 
pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1)   
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)  
... 
pd.concat([df2, df3, df4, df5], axis=1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you expecting one single dataframe as an output, or separate outputs for each `pd.concat` call?

Comment: I expected separate outputs for each pd.concat call, because I want to use each of them for a greedy correlation step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

dfs_in_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]

combinations = []
for length in range(2, len(dfs_in_list)):
    combinations.extend(list(itertools.combinations(dfs_in_list, length)))


for c in combinations:
    pd.concat(c, axis=1)
```